# how to specify an account by name in require_auth('_self');

Tags: cleos

Instead of using require_auth('_self') is it possible to specify a single or many users, somthing like

```
require_auth('bob');
```

or

```
require_auth(["bob", "alice"]);
```

the rest of the contract is

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>

In the chat @Ami below provided the below solution....

class [[eosio::contract]] hello : public contract {
  public:
    using contract::contract;

    [[eosio::action]]
      void myactiontwo( name user, std::string day_name) {
        if (user == name("bob") || user == name("alice")) {
          require_auth(user);
          print("Hey, ", user, " today is ", day_name);
        } else {
          require_auth(_self);
        }
    }     
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user name is equal to "bob" or "alice", make sure they have the keys to sign the transaction.

All other users are not allowed to run this action.

```
if(user==name("bob") || user==name("alice")){
  require_auth(user);
}else{
  print("user must be bob or alice");
  require_auth(_self); // will fail for any account other than the owner of the contract.
}
```

Comment: Ami, I added the rest of the contract above, When compiling this I get the error pointing to the || ...
/Users/myname/Documents/contracts/hello/hello.cpp:11:35: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'void')
        require_auth(name("bob")) || require_auth(name("alice"));
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Sorry, I may have misguided you. The require_auth does not return a boolean so can't be used with the OR operator ||.

What exactly are you trying to test here? Are you asking if bob or alica are trying to call this action?

Comment: No problem, I want to make sure that only bob or alice can view the line that gets printed "Hey, bob today is Monday` when i issue `cleos push action hello myactiontwo '["bob", "Monday"]' -p bob@active`

Comment: In that case, you need to check if the signing user is equal to name('bob') or name('alice')

Comment: Ah ok, could you help me with the syntax?

Comment: Look at https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/your-first-contract
They are demonstrating both the user variable and the signing account usage.

Comment: Yes I've had a look at this and it shows how to ensure only the account that published the contract can call the contract with _self and user. It does show how to ensure the message that gets printed includes the name of the user who called the contract, it doesn't restrict the function execution to a specified name or names

Comment: I edited my answer. You check the user variable from the action and if it matches "bob" or "alice", you make sure they are not just claiming to be those accounts, but that they have authorization using the require_auth(_self). All other accounts are not checked and just return early from the function call.

Comment: It looks good but on trying to compile it I get... error: invalid operands to binary expression ('eosio::name' and 'const char *')
      if(name(user) == "bob" || name(user) == "alice") {

Comment: Try comparing like this: user == N("bob") || user == N("alice")

Comment: I gave it a whirl but a new error.... /Users/myname/Documents/contracts/hello/hello.cpp:11:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'N'
      if(user == N("bob") || user == N("alice")) {

Comment: Sorry, I'm not in front of my dev tools, so just from memory and this changed several times. Perhaps the correct way is: if(user==name("bob") || user==name("alice")

Comment: I've edited the above and it compiles, and I can set it with cleos set contract hello /Users/myname/Documents/contracts/hello -p hello@active and when I call it with cleos push action hello myactiontwo '["sam", "sunday"]' -p bob@active I get the error Error 3090004: Missing required authority I guess its because bob does not fulfill the requirement of _self if I call it with the account hello like this cleos push action hello myactiontwo '["sam", "sunday"]' -p hello@active it works but as expected it doesn't print, but it shouldn't as this user is hello not bob or alice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95821/discussion-between-ami-heines-and-bill).